# How to fix "no compiler can produce code for this qt version" in Qt6 beta?

Tags: windows, qt, qt-creator, qt6

I am eager to test the beta release of Qt6 on a Windows 10 machine.

For the alpha version I have followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZOlZozJNpQU) by voidrealms and it worked.

However, when I install the beta2 (6.0.0-202010220944), I cannot use it, as the kit is not available. The error says:

> no compiler can produce code for this qt version. Please define one or more compilers for:
>
> x86-windows-msys-pe-64bit

[image: Qt version]

Searching for a solution of this error, I read this [topic](https://forum.qt.io/topic/34625/no-compiler-can-produce-code-for-this-qt-version). However, it does not help me getting further, because I already have the latest (and updated) version of MSVC 2019 installed.

Here are the installed and detected compilers:

[image: Qt Creator settings]

I realise it is a beta version and there might/should be problems. However, is it possible to make this work?

Comment: I'm not positive, but doesn't `x86-windows-msys-pe-64bit` mean qmake was built with mingw, rather than MSVC++?

Comment: @JarMan, I have no idea. I do not use mingw. The version I have installed claims to be for MSVC2019 64 bit.

Comment: Try looking at the ABI for a qmake that does work for you (e.g. 5.xx). Does it use that same "msys" name, or does it use something else?

Comment: @JarMan, I have removed it before the installation of the beta and the alpha is not available anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this to be an error by Qt. If Qt Creator is telling you that the ABI for that version of qmake is `x86-windows-msys-pe-64bit`, then that means it was built with the mingw compiler. If it had been built with MSVC, you should see `x86-windows-msvc2019-pe-64bit`. I would report it as a bug.

In the meantime, if you wanted to test out Qt6, you could install mingw.